# How to convert a List< Long> into a double[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream

I am trying to convert a `List<Long>` to a `double[]` in Java,

I did in the following way,

```
  List<Long> longList = ........;

  int len = longList.size();

  double[] doubleArray = new double[len];

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
     doubleArray[i] = (double) longList.get(i);
```

**I am wondering if I can do it in a smarter way (and how)** since I'm using `Java-8`, I saw some conversion using the stream method. But couldn't find anything that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed do it using a stream:

```
double[] result = longList.stream()
                          .mapToDouble(Long::doubleValue)
                          .toArray();
```

It's maybe a little shorter and cleaner but you won't gain anything performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
double[] doubleArray = longList.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 try this:

```
list.stream().map(v -> (double)v)
    .toArray(Double[]::new);
```